# How to interact with phonegap application with iphone xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

I'm working on phone gap application and now I want to fore hence my application in xcode not in phone gap. Can anyone help me with regarding this issue. If any sample code or tutorial you have then please let me know.

Comment: Someone please help me. it's very urgent me to know!!!!!!

Comment: It's very unclear what your trying to do. But you can execute Javascript expressions in a web view using the `stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:` method. e.g: `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:@"someFunction()"]`.

Comment: hai Mattias, Actually I've demo project done in phonegap and I need to finished it in iphone. But I don't understand I to continue the project from phonegap to xcode. please help me.

Comment: How did you develop the demo project? and what do you mean by "demo project done in phonegap"? phonegap runs on many platforms and works by providing a web view and a Javascript API for accessing some native functions.

Comment: My demo project is for all platform but i need to extends the project in iphone only. BTW Thanx for your time I'll talk with you tommorow.

Comment: You should probably start by following the steps at https://phonegap.com/start/#ios-x4

Answer (score 1):

You have to recode all your app. Phone gap code isn't native code.